# How to make twitter Bootstrap Plugin Wordpress take effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have downloaded and activated the Twitter Bootstrap Plugin but I am confused as to what it involves.

I currently have the default Twenty Thirteen theme active and I assumed that the Bootstrap plugin would just override its settings.

Do I still need to download a Bootstrap THEME as well as the PLUGIN if I want the appearance of the website to come from TB and not the Twenty Thirteen? How to I get rid of any pre-existing themes so as to get Twitter Bootstrap to build the interface without manually modifying the code?

Comment: Try JBST, see https://github.com/bassjobsen/jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme. Or something more basic i found today: http://bragthemes.com/twitter-bootstrap-3-wordpress-starter-theme/

Comment: Thanks Bass, but I alread have the Bootstrap Plugin (not theme) and was wondering how to make it take effect, do you need to still download a bootstrap theme? Cheers

Comment: What's the url of the plugin? I expect the plugin only load Bootstrap's CSS and javascript. You will need a theme written in / for Boostrap too in that case. What do you expect or need from the plugin?

Comment: THanks for your response. It is the http://www.icontrolwp.com plugin. When you download and install it you get a menu with CSS and LESS set up options in your blog/wp-admin area. However, no matter what you change, it does not affect the pages which are under the default Wordpress theme. Do you still need to add a Bootstrap theme in that case? What is the point of the plugin then? Thanks

Comment: Yes you still need a boostrap theme, see: http://www.icontrolwp.com/faqs/what-problem-wordpress-twitter-bootstrap-plugin-solve/ The point of the plugin will be keep you bootstrap's files uptodate (could break your theme!) and teh use of shortcodes as described here: http://www.icontrolwp.com/our-wordpress-plugins/wordpress-shortcodes-demo/ http://www.icontrolwp.com/our-wordpress-plugins/wordpress-shortcodes-demo/ Note this demo use Twitter's Bootstrap 2.3.2 and not version 3

Comment: Thank again Bass. I have been trying to install the boostrap-3 theme above but I keep getting this error: "The theme is missing the <code>style.css</code> stylesheet". Is there another version?

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. The zip file was inside the main "zip" file so WP could not find the theme folders. Thanks